# Need regex search and replace through hundreds of Wordpress pages - where to start?

Tags: html, regex, wordpress, replace

I need to clean the content of a wordpress site where the client has used the visual editor to style content across hundreds of pages resulting in a mess of nested span and style tags that need replacing with a simple class.

For example - I need to replace:

```
<h2 style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #800080;"><strong>Page Heading</strong></span></h2>
```

with this:

```
<h2 class="myclass">Page Heading</h2>
```

I think the following regex search will get me where I want to go (though I know I need to read up on escaping):

```
<h2 style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #800080;"><strong>(.*?):</strong></span></h2>
```

But I have no database experience and would appreciate guidance on the best tool for the job / best approach to this.

I have tried the Search Regex plugin which works well on posts but does not work at all on pages. Remarkably (as I'm sure I am not the first or last that needs to clean up the html across a large number of WP pages) I can find no alternative plugin to perform this task on pages.

Comment: I would probably use an editor to do a mass find/replace. ex: Sublime Text

Comment: thanks - Sublime Text seems to support regex find and replace which is a start. Can I just use a plain text search and replace like this on a SQL database file without any nasty surprises?

Comment: Yep, but keep in mind computers only do what you tell it to do, so if the plain text matches some other part of the file you shouldn't be touching, you'll need to fix that.

Comment: regex here would be hard to guarantee. how's your php, use `DOMDocument`. that would be the safest. you could test for a pattern of styles to know which class to set, easily and safely strip/save/replace etc etc... that is what it was designed for. do in batches if lots/big posts

Answer (score 0):

My mistake - advised that the Search Regex plugin does search Pages but that my regex query is wrong - thus no results!